# RGB Normalizied give Black image

Tags: c++, opencv

Here , I am trying to do normalize RGB image.

Here is my code.

```
cv::Mat channels[3], normalize_rgb;
    split(image, channels);

    for (int i = 0; i < image.size().height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.size().width; j++)
        {
            int b = (int)(image).at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
            int g = (int)(image).at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
            int r = (int)(image).at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[2];

                            double sum = b + g + r;
            double bnorm = b / sum * 255;
            double gnorm = g / sum * 255;
            double rnorm = r / sum * 255;

            channels[0].at<uchar>(i, j) = bnorm;
            channels[1].at<uchar>(i, j) = gnorm;
            channels[2].at<uchar>(i, j) = rnorm;
        }
    }
    merge(channels, 3, normalize_rgb);
    normalize = normalize_rgb.clone();
```

**Problem:**  after normalizing r,g, b value is giving me very small value which turns to 0. and hence I get black image.

Anyone can please help me to figure out problems. thanks

Comment: Anyone else.. can suggest something?

Comment: Other than the already identified problems (sum instead of mean, missing saturation), why so much code? `image * (255 / cv::mean(image.reshape(1))[0])`

Comment: I have fixed it. But still I am getting black image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change image to `double` first. It is black because when you divide `int` by `int` you get zero. And then you're trying to set `uchar = double` which is completely wrong.

Try: 
`double bnorm = double (b) / sum * 255;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide the `sum` by the number of pixels.

In a 1000x1000 image you want to divide by the average, not by one million times the average.

Note that dividing by the average may give you values bigger than 255 (values higher than the average) so clamping is required after the scaling. Probably a better solution would be aiming at the average becoming 128, not 255 with

```
double bnorm = b * k;
double gnorm = g * k;
double rnorm = r * k;
```

where `k` is computed once per image as

```
double average = sum / (image.size().height*image.size().width);
double k = 127.0 / average;
```

but note that this can still produce values higher than 255 in output.

If you want to stretch you need to normalize with the maximum value, not with the average and in this case clamping is not needed.

Comment: bnorm , gnorm, rnorm are still very small, and gives me black image.

Comment: Well, nborm gives me same value if I multiple first or divide first.

Comment: @Abc when you normalise a uniform grey127 image, what is the value of sum? It has to be 127.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link which related to [RGB Normalization](https://akash0x53.github.io/blog/2013/04/29/RGB-Normalization/), there is a  mathematical list in the article.

So actually, u need to divide a var total, and each total is just the sum of each pixel, not the whole image(width() * height()). Maybe you should try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < image.size().height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < image.size().width; j++)
    {
        int b = (int)(image).at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
        int g = (int)(image).at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
        int r = (int)(image).at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[2];
        int sum = b + g  + r;

        double bnorm = b / sum * 255;
        double gnorm = g / sum * 255;
        double rnorm = r / sum * 255;

        channels[0].at<uchar>(i, j) = bnorm;
        channels[1].at<uchar>(i, j) = gnorm;
        channels[2].at<uchar>(i, j) = rnorm;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i haven't got any opencv skills yet, but i tried to use this operation to the raw pixels, and then write to a bitmap. from the pic created, it works. So maybe you should try to add break point before merge to check the true value in channels.

Comment: I did. my normalize values are very small than actual b,g,r values.